# WebForms Server Controls

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I know this is basic but I have trouble connecting marketing words with the technology.

On the APS.NET web site there are references to WebForms Server Controls
Is that the controls in System.Web.UI Namespace?

If I am porting a (non-MVVM) WPF business application to ASP.NET I am assume WebForms would be the likely candidate.

Comment: [Web Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsyt68f1(v=vs.90).aspx)

for example-
    <asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" otherattributes...>     </asp:Label>

Comment: @NicholasV. The specific question is namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More precise, ASP.Net Web Server Controls are under -

[System.Web.UI.WebControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx) namespace.

In addition, all ASP.Net Web Server controls inherit from `WebControl`.

Comment: So if I am not finding a FlowDocumentScrollViewer in System.Web.UI.WebControls I can conclude it is not available in ASP.NET?

Comment: @Blam You are correct; FlowDocumentScrollViewer is under [System.Windows.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 1):

> On the APS.NET web site there are references to WebForms Server
>   Controls Is that the controls in System.Web.UI Namespace?

Yes.

Comment: I don't know if you or Win answered first.

Answer (score 0):

WebForms is the web based analog to WinForms and shares a similar event model.  WebForms has an extensive set of base controls for handling routing data capture (e.g. date, file upload, form inputs) and display tasks (e.g. data tables, repeaters, labels).  In addition to that you can create your own controls either from scratch or from inheriting other controls.  When developing your own controls you have the option of developing User Controls or Server Controls.  Both have strengths and weaknesses.  User Controls are usually easier to develop but are intended to be application specific and aren't easily shared between projects.  Server Controls on the other hand are more complex to develop and can easily be embedded into libraries that can easily be shared between libraries.

If you're porting an application from WPF or WinForms, you'll probably be using a lot of the base controls and only creating User or Server controls when a base control doesn't provide the needed functionality.